# Do I need to sell all stocks before new year in order to claim money lost in stocks?

Tags: united-states, taxes, stocks, capital-gains-tax

For example, I made $1000 dollars in stock market on the first half year. I sold $500 worth of stock. So I have $500 still in the market and $500 in cash. Then I bought $4000 new stocks in the 2nd half year. In December, the $4000 stocks dropped to only $2000 in value. So in total, I lost $1000 this year.

In order to claim the $1000 net lost in tax credit, do I need to sell all the stocks  before the new year? If I don’t sell off the stocks, will I have to pay the tax for the $500 that I made in the first half year by selling the stocks?

Comment: Yes on both counts. Only realized losses are tax relevant.

Comment: You haven't lost any money until you actually sell the stock for less than you paid for it.

Comment: Your math doesn't add up. You say you "made $1000" but had $500 in stock and $500 in cash after selling. How much did you pay for the stock that made $1000? Then you say you lost $2000 in the second half so lost $1000 in total. $500 - $2000 = -$1500, not -$1000.

Comment: I'm just trying to make sure you know that you're taxed on _gains_ and _losses_, not on the total amount that you sold for. So you may not have to pay tax on all $500.

Comment: And secondly, you only need to sell enough to realize a loss big enough to offset the gain.

Comment: *You haven't lost any money until you actually sell the stock for less than you paid for it.*  That is incorrect.  At this point in time he has lost the money but he hasn't realized the loss.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: Yes.

You have to sell the stock in order to take the loss on your taxes. So, if your $4000 worth of stock is now priced at $2000 and you sold it, you would have a loss of -$2000. This is, technically, a "short term" loss, since the stock was held less than a year. You would then net it out against and other short term gains and losses for the year. Your first trade is a little unclear, so I'm going to assume you bought the stock for $X, the stock then went up $1000, and you sold half, realizing $500 in gain. So, you net the two for a combined -$1500 short term loss.

After all short term sales are accounted for, you then net it against any long term gains (gains on any stock held longer than a year, which you sold this year) or losses.

After that, any negative amount can be taken as a tax deduction, up to a limit of -$3000 in any given year. Any additional losses over that amount are rolled over to the next year's taxes.

Note: you said "tax credit". It's not a credit, it's a deduction on your taxes. It reduces the amount of your taxable income.

Note #2: if you buy back the stock within 30 days, the wash sale rule applies, and you can't take the loss.

Note #3: if all you want to do is not pay taxes on that earlier $500 gain, you can simply sell $500 of the losing stock. Since you bought that for $1000, you'd have a -$500 loss for a net short term gain/loss for the year of $0.